# Вопрос по массивам js, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть например такой код

```
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".anything")
let z = document.querySelectorAll(".close")
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].onclick = close;
    function close(){
    z[i].style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

как этот код можно писать на jQuery? там вроде нет SelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как-то так, но лучше отталкиваться от позиции в `DOM-дереве`, а не от порядкового номера.

```
$(".anything").click(function(){
  var index = $(".anything").index(this);
  $(".close").eq(index).hide();
})
```

Comment: ответ могу принять через 5 мин. Ваш ответ тот самый)